# mod_rewrite not working codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i am trying to remove `index.php` from `url` in `codeigniter` usign `.htaccess`

my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

my `application/config/config.php` setting:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

now when i go at: `http://localhost/myProject` it works.. and call the default `home controller`

when i go at: `http://localhost/myproject/home` it says:

```
The requested URL /myproject/home/ was not found on this server.
```

but when i go at: `http://localhost/myproject/index.php/home`

it again works and call the default `home controller`

i am using `centos 6.5` while the same setting works perfect on `windows 8 localhost`

please help, any suggestion or help would be a great help .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have edited the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to `AllowOverride` all:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

   AllowOverride All

</Directory>
```

and now it is working as aspected... :)

Comment: There are so many other similar questions out there and this seemed to be the only working solution in my case

Comment: For those who cannot find the path specified, and your server is running on apache.. you must instead edit your '/etc/apache2/apache2.conf' and paste the above solution removing the quotes around var/www/html

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: sir can you explain me different between `your .htaccess` code and `my .htaccess` code actually i am new to `.htaccess`